# iOS: Foursquare shout or creating event

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, foursquare

I am working with foursquare a for the first time, having hard time with this: Is there any API from the foursquare that supports function to allow shout out? If there is can someone tell me the link. I am really stuck with this stuff..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is latest and working [FSQDemo](https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api) works with iOS5 and Xcode4.2 tested. Please read Readme.md first, you need to create your application and put your clientid as mentioned in it.

When you run the application you can get check in and before you do that you have to click on obtain access token.

According to [this](http://aboutfoursquare.com/what-is-a-shout/)  A shout is Foursquare’s version of a status update or a tweet and from this [forum discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/foursquare-api/browse_thread/thread/37d14e21207d8127) it is passing shout as parameter to url. So there may/must be a way from this sample as it allows check in.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Jennis.. hmm but is there any way to post and update / shout without checking in to places? I mean just posting plain status as facebook / twitter do?

Comment: according to documents at foursquare http://support.foursquare.com/entries/317496-what-is-a-shout they have stopped stand alone shouts and now shouts should always be attached to a check-in. Hope this helps

Comment: yeah.. I also saw it earlier.. I just have to confirm.. thanks.. :D now its clear..

Comment: Enjoying helping as getting lots of support from our community and proud of giving something valuable back to community.

Answer (score 2):

there is a good example in github for this,hope that helps you. :

> https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-iOS-API

Comment: thanks sarah.. but it seems it has the old version.. :( anyway, I appreciate your help.. :)

Comment: oh k...not an issue..happy to help.. also you can try with google,there are links available.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.. Thanks with this > https://github.com/baztokyo/foursquare-ios-api/blob/master/README.md